# What is the usual high availability/failover solution for Jenkins CI?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

What is the usual high availability/failover solution for Jenkins? Right now in its default configuration its a single point of failure.

I understand CloudBees ships their plugin with an Enterprise Jenkins version - is that the standard? What other solutions are there?

Answer (score 3):

Diptanu Choudry put a [a presentation on youtube using Jenkins as the backbone of a high availability continuous delivery setup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E87hhMgquwc) in Jan 2013. Yes, he mention CloudBees as having a failover solution. He also discusses the pieces you need to do it yourself. I'm hoping he'll post notes, but in the meantime the video/audio is 90 minutes long and is on youtube. **NB** the talk starts 7 minutes in.